# Where does json web token save the data?

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have a node-app using json web token:

var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

If a login succedes then this library creates a token this way:

```
var payload = {mydata: 'abcd'};
var token = jwt.sign(payload, 'secret', {
    expiresIn: 28800
});

return {
    success: true,
    message: 'Success',
    token: token
};
```

What I don't understand is where the token is stored on the server.
If the same user that received the token makes a call to a protected resource, then I have this line:

```
jwt.verify(token_sent_by_used, 'secret', function (err, res) {
    if(!err){
        res.json({result: 'success'});
    }
    else{
        res.json({result: 'failure'});
    }
}
```

The reason why Im asking this is that I could not find explanation on how to handle jwt when running an application across several machines.
If my backend is put on different machines and user makes the requests to a load balancer, then the request can hit any machine.
If jwt writes token data on the file system, then I guess there can be issue if the request hits a machine that was not the one that created the token.
When using session, you can set the session handler to database. How do you solve this with jwt?

****EDIT****

Ok, let's take an eaxmple.
I have a node app that is running on machine .10 and the same node app also running on machine .11. Two different machines.

I go to machine .10 and send username password. App on machine .10 checks username/password. They are ok. Machine .10 creates a jwt token and send it to me.

I now make a curl request (to a resource that requires a valid jwt-token) to machine .11 and send the jwt-token that machine .10 had preciously sent to me. Machine .11 will not complain about the jtw-token? It will be considered valid? Even if it was not created on machine .11?

Comment: Jwt token are not stored on server. After creating jwt token server send that token to user/browser. You can then save that token to either in app state, browser's localstorage or browser's session storage.

Comment: Please have a look at the edited question.

Comment: Jwt token has nothing to do with machine. You just need the same secret key on both machine to decrypt/encrypt the token.

Comment: Jwt token is just some data encrypted with a certain key. As long as some machine has that key, it can decrypt it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both servers in your question must be able to verify the token - they must be able to generate the signature. If both servers share the same secret key (used to originally generate the token's signature on .10), then both would be able to verify its contents.

In the screenshot below, both the red part and the purple part are plaintext - anyone can read and modify them. However, the blue part is special - it can only be generated on the server, **from** the red and purple parts, **using** the secret key. So, it guarantees that the red and purple parts were not tampered with.

[image]

So, when you send the whole JTW back to a server, it can use the secret key to generate the blue part and compare it with the blue part that you're sending. If they don't match, then someone (illegitimately) changed the red or purple parts, so authentication is denied.

Answer (score 3):

JWTs aren't stored on the server.

When your server hands out a JWT, it's giving the client a visitor's pass that can be used whenever it requests a resource. As long as the client keeps hold of it, and it remains valid (i.e. not expired), it can show it to the server with the request and the server will respond accordingly.

The server knows it's a valid pass because it signed it with it's secret.

As for running on several machines, as long as any server that needs to verify the token knows the secret, it can do so.

**Edit to clarify the above**

You're asking specifically whether machine A will accept a token that was issued by machine B.

The only requirement for accepting a token is validating the signature so that you can verify where it came from.

If machine A and machine B share the secret, their tokens are interchangeable. There's no difference at all in the two and machine A won't be able to tell if it issued the token, or machine B did.

Comment: I've clarified my last line a bit for you. if machines .10 and .11 have the same key, their tokens are interchangable

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere, the token is not saved in the server. In the [documentation](https://jwt.io/introduction/) you can read

> Authentication: This is the most common scenario for using JWT. Once the user is logged in, each subsequent request will include the JWT, allowing the user to access routes, services, and resources that are permitted with that token.

You have to understand:

- When you receive a login request, you return the token to the user (if the request is valid)
- On every request, the client will send you back the token, and you will be able to verify if this token correspond to the one you sent. Most of the time, the token will be provided in the request header, so on the server side you will be able to access it using `req.headers[<token_property_here>]`

Then to verify, you will need to run this kind of code

```
jwt.verify(req.headers['x-auth-token'], 'secret', function (err, res) {
    if(err){
        return res.json({result: 'failure'});
    }
    // Else do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With jwt you can save the token on the client. Usually on localStorage or sessionStorage, then you send the token every time you make a request in the authorization header.
Or like the [stormpath](https://stormpath.com/blog/jwt-the-right-way) recommended way, you save the jwt on a cookie with **httpOnly and secure flags** (read the explanation). 
So every time your user needs to access a resource you need to check the cookie.
In express when you create the jwt you save it to cookie with:

```
res.cookie('token', jwt, { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
```

Then you can create a middleware that verify the authentication.

```
const UserAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {

        const token = req.cookies.token; //if cookie not exist, user is not authenticated (httpOnly flag)    

        jwt.verify(token_sent_by_used, 'secret', function (err, res) {
                if (!err) {
                    req.token = res.validToken;
                    next();
                } else {
                    res.send('Not authenticated');
                }
        });
};

//In your endpoint you use like:<br/>
router.get('/someEndPoint', userAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
      // use the token here.
      const token = req.token;
    ...
});
```

Then when make a request on the client don't forget to add **withCredentials** that will allow the browser send the cookies.

```
 superagent.post(url)
    .withCredentials()            
    .send(_msg);
```

That's all that you need.